# Merging file line for line error

Tags: unix, paste

I have two files of the same length that I want to merge line per line. Here are my files for example:

FileA.txt

```
DM  CM127861    chr14   103390285   +   NM_030943   AMN Megaloblasticanaemia1   
DM  CM118934    chr14   103395855   +   NM_030943   AMN Megaloblasticanaemia1   
DM  CM127864    chr14   103395992   +   NM_030943   AMN Megaloblasticanaemia1   
DM  CM088131    chr14   103395814   +   NM_030943   AMN Megaloblasticanaemia1   
DM  CM124403    chr14   103395776   +   NM_030943   AMN Imerslund-Gr‰sbecksyndrome
DM  CM002932    chr1    115220593   -   NM_000036   AMPD1   Adenosinemonophosphatedeaminasedeficiency
    etc
```

FileB.txt

```
TGT    C    TAT    Y
ATG    M    AAG    K
CAG    Q    GAG    E
CCG    P    TCG    S
CCG    P    CTG    L
GCG    A    GTG    V
```

and I want my final output to be:

```
DM  CM127861    chr14   103390285   +   NM_030943   AMN Megaloblasticanaemia1    TGT    C   TAT    Y
etc
```

To do this, I've been using this paste command: `paste -d '\t' FileA.txt FileB.txt > combined.txt` However, I keep getting this error `Error reading FileA.txt`. I'm pretty sure that it has something to do with my `%` sign. I tried to change all the %'s in my file to another character, but then it ran into another character it couldn't process. I'm pretty sure it will keep running into these errors throughout my file, because it has some unusual characters. Is there any other way to merge files line for line when some unusual characters are present?

ls -l for the two files below:

`-rw-r--r--@ 1 christy  staff  4811597 Aug 27 14:18 Translated.txt`

`-rw-r--r--  1 christy  staff  846004 Aug 27 14:18 Translated2.txt`

Comment: Can you try to find more information? `ls -l` as @Jens suggested; `cat FileA.txt FileB.txt` to see if the problem is paste-specific, `paste -d '\t' FileB.txt FileB.txt` to see if the problem is FileA.txt specific.

Comment: @WalterA I updated my post with `ls -l` and the `cat` worked fine.

Comment: When I try your command on copied versions of your files, I see no error and the paste is successful.  Is it possible to include sufficient raw material in your question that the problem can be replicated?

Comment: Perhaps Translated.txt is shorter or has some very special chars. Check the length with `wc -l Translated*.txt` of debug with a smaller subset: `head -10 Translated.txt > a; head -10 Translated2.txt > b; paste -d '\t' a b`.
When this works try more lines (100, 500, 3000) until you know where the problem is: `while [ 1 ]; do read nr_lines; head -${nr_lines} Translated.txt > a; head -${nr_lines} Translated2.txt > b; paste -d '\t' a b | tail -5; done`

Comment: Is this on an Apple with IOS?

Comment: @Jens it is an Apple with IOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't replicate the problem you're having based on the data you've included in your question, so ... here's an awk-based alternative to `paste`.

```
awk '{getline B < "fileB.txt"; print $0 "\t" B;}' fileA.txt > combined.txt
```

This steps through fileA.txt and for each line it reads the next line of fileB.txt and prints the two together.

This has an advantage over an array based merge like:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$0;next;} {print $0 "\t" a[FNR];}' fileB.txt fileA.txt
```

in that it doesn't require all of one of the files to be loaded into memory.  Of course, if you have the memory for it, reading one file at a time may run faster than reading each file line by line.  The results, if successful, should be the same.

Comment: This worked perfectly. I'm not sure why i couldn't get the paste to work. Thank you though. Now I'm not stuck :)

Answer (score 1):

There's something you are not telling us. For example, this works without a problem:

```
$ paste FileA.txt FileB.txt
Syndrome    ATG Y
Syndrome%    AGT        K
```

If you get an "Error reading FileA.txt" that's more of an indication that the file might be nonexistent or you have no read permission. What does

```
ls -l *.txt
```

say? Are you by chance unaware of Unix's case sensitivity in file names?

**EDIT**: Could be related to extended attributes. You can list them with

```
$ xattr -l FileA.txt
```

or

```
$ ls -l@ *.txt
```

Since the "funny" character in your file, judging by the name of the physician, should be a-umlaut as in Imerslund-Gräsbeck, it might be encoding related. If the `ls -l@` showed something like `com.apple.TextEncoding` appearing, try removing that attribute with

```
$ xattr -d com.apple.TextEncoding FileA.txt
```

If other attributes show up, like `com.apple.quarantine`, delete them as well.

Comment: Definitely not case sensitivity in file names because it will output the file up to a specified character, but will then stop merging. When I then remove the character that I think is causing the problem, then it will merge further lines until it hits another character that causes a problem.

Comment: My file is kind of complicated so I didn't post an exact excerpt from my file, but maybe I should do so.

Comment: I've updated my post with an exact example from my file

Comment: @christylynn002 What does the `@` in the ls output mean? Does `man ls` describe its interpretation?

Comment: @christylynn002 I've done some research; the `@` means *extended attributes* which you can list with `ls -le *.txt`. Another wild guess: are you perhaps running out of disk space?

Comment: Extended attributes, disk space? Can you perform `cp Translated.txt Translated3.txt` and paste with Translated3.txt?

Comment: Sorry about my delay in responding. Got super sick. Anyways, I did `ls -l@ *.txt` and got the `com.apple.TextEncoding` response. I think tried the `$ xattr -d com.apple.TextEncoding FileA.txt` command but that gave me an error: `xattr: FileA.txt: No such xattr: com.apple.TextEncoding`